# How can I add a shortcut of App to Spotlight database?

Tags: macos, emacs

I want to use nightly builds of Emacs in OSX so I've done like this.

```
$ brew install emacs --cocoa --use-git-head --HEAD
$ mv /Applications/Emacs.app /Applications/Emacs.app.stable
$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/Emacs.app /Applications/Emacs.app
```

It works almost fine. The only problem is that I can not launch emacs from Spotlight.
How can I make Spotlight recognize soft link in Applications folder?

Comment: If you put it on your dock and type ctrl+f3, then type the letter `e` (for Emacs.app) or type the letters `ema` quickly (if you have more than one app on your dock beginning with the letter e), and then press return key, that will launch Emacs.  There is also a cheap program called keyboard maestro, that will let you set up your own keyboard shortcuts and macros.  You could also switch to Finder using command+tab, and then type command+shift+a to open the applications folder, and then do the same dance ... type the letter `e` or `ema` and then command+down-arrow to open Emacs.app.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I'd use ctrl+f3 way, if I can't change Spotlight behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I used the Automator to create an Emacs.app that I saved in /Applications.  I used a bash script/hack that should always select the latest version of emacs in the brew Cellar:

The text of the bash script I used was:

```
open $(ls -1d /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/* | sort | tail -1)/Emacs.app
```

Comment: The image link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was install [Emacs for Mac OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com/). You might want to check it.

Comment: I installed nightly build, because there is bug fix that I needed.

Comment: There are nightly builds available: http://emacsformacosx.com/builds

Comment: please read the question. I've installed nightly build already.

Comment: I've read it, and I understand you already have. I was just suggesting Emacs for Mac OS X as an alternative since it gets indexed by Spotlight with no additional set up. I pointed you to the nightly builds to get the version you may need.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your advice. But I wanted to use brew to control apps. And above that I want to know how to Spotlight database works and How to change it.